# Double-Ended Queue - Have I over-engineered it again?

Tags: c++, queue, memory-management

I'm working on an implementation of the Double-Ended Queue as a Doubly-Linked List (for personal enrichment), and I was wondering if anyone minded taking a look at my Constructor/Destructor and Empty functions to see if I'm on the right track.  It should be self-explanatory enough on it's own (I hope).

```
    DeQueue::DeQueue() {
        // set up the sentinels
        head = new QueueItem();
        tail = new QueueItem();

        head->next = tail;
        tail->last = head;

        head->data = NULL;
        tail->data = NULL;
        tail->next = head->last = NULL;
    }

   DeQueue::~DeQueue() {
    QueueItem* current = head;
    QueueItem* next;
    current = current->next;
    for (;current != tail; current = current->next){
        delete current->last;
    }
    delete current;
    }

    bool DeQueue::Empty() {
        return tail->last == head;
    }
```

The idea is that the two `head` and `tail` sentinels will always remain at the ends, so the easiest way to check if it is empty is to determine if `head` points to `tail` or vice versa.  Also, in my destructor, I start at the tail and delete everything from there back, sentinels included.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**  The destructor now moves forward one node, deletes what's behind it, then moves on.  Sound like a better approach?

Answer (score 4):

I would make it so that you only have one sentanal.

Then the list is empty when head and tail point at the same object.

```
DeQueue::DeQueue()
    // set up the sentinels
    : head(new QueueItem())   // prefer to use initialize list.
    , tail(head)              // Make sure your declarations are in the correct order.
{

    head->next = head;        // Circular linked list.
    head->last = head;

    head->data = NULL;        // No data in the fake node.
}
```

Your delete loop does not actually move:

```
while(current->next != head)
{
    delete current->next;  // your deleting the element
                           // But not moving the the current item
                           // So the loop will not exit.
}


DeQueue::~DeQueue()
{
    // Delete from the head.
    // Just slowly loop over the nodes deleting them as you go
    while(head != tail)
    {
         QueueItem* old = head;
         head           = head->next;

         delete old;
    }
    // Delete the sentanal object created in the constructor.
    delete tail;
}

// Simplify empty.
bool DeQueue::Empty()
{
    return tail == head;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even realize that.  I think I'll stick with the dual sentinels for now (I'm a bit brain-dead at the moment) but how about this for the destructor? (check original post)

Comment: @wtfsven: Your destructor now works. But you should still use the initializaer list in your constructor.

Comment: +1 for initializer lists. Also, the QueueItem should set data to NULL in its constructor, so you don't need to worry about doing that in DeQueue.

Comment: @dominic: That depends. QueueItem may be a plain old POD type so adding a constructor will change its layout and some gurantees. Also if QueueItem is fully contained as a private member class of DeQueue then being so strict on its construction may not be beneficial when DeQueue is going to manage all its interactions anyway.